# What are the correct lyrics used in Disclosure's song "Latch"?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I heard this song and read the lyrics. There is a part that goes like this:

> I'm so encaptured, got me wrapped up in your touch
>
> Feel so enamored, hold me tight within your clutch
>
> How do you do it, you got me losing every breath
>
> What did you give me to make my heart **beat** out my chest?

After that, I heard Pentatonix version of the song that was mashed up with Naughty Boy's song "La La La".

When I read the lyrics for this version, they said:

> I'm so encaptured, got me wrapped up in your touch
>
> Feel so enamored, hold me tight within your clutch
>
> How do you do it, you got me losing every breath
>
> What did you give me to make my heart **bleed** out my chest?

So, which lyrics are correct? Do they both have the same meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discogs is a record collecting site, on which I found the release featuring Latch. [The LP release](http://www.discogs.com/Disclosure-Settle/release/4618675) features the below picture of the lyrics sleeve.

Although the quality isn't the best, you can clearly see that the official lyrics are:

> What did you give me to make my heart beat out my chest?

[image: Settle lyrics]

As for the meaning of the phrase, it certainly feels like a metaphore for strong feelings, or love. The singer is obviously feeling so much that the heart beats so intensely that it is about to beat out of the chest, metaphorically speaking.

Having a bleeding heart is somewhat differend. See the definition from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bleeding%20heart):

> a person who shows extravagant sympathy especially for an object of alleged persecution

It could be seen as an over sensetive person.